# Maven execute module pom using profile from parent pom

Tags: maven, fabric8

I want to build docker images using profile in parent pom, which looks like this:

```
...
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.39.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>image-build</id>
            <modules>
                <module>hot.build</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
...
```

My hot.build module`s pom looks like this

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.39.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <id>build-server-image</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>...</name>
                                    <build>
                                        ...
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <id>build-emailService-image</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <name>...</name>
                                    <build>
                                       ...
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Running mvn clean install -Pimage-build executes hot.build with success, but it is not actually doing the build phase.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the Maven output?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CAsDYwsG